# nettle-3.0 and gmp-6.0.0 - undefined symbols "gmpz_limbs_write, gmpz_limbs_read..."

Tags: gmp, gnutls

I am trying to compile `nettle` 3.0 with `gmp` 6.0.0 and I kept getting missing symbols:

```
Making all in tools
gcc -g -O2 -ggdb3 -Wno-pointer-sign -Wall -W   -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes   -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wnested-externs -L..  pkcs1-conv.o misc.o ../getopt.o ../getopt1.o -lhogweed -lnettle -lgmp -o pkcs1-conv
ld: warning: relocation error: R_386_32: file ../getopt.o: symbol optarg: external symbolic relocation against non-allocatable section .debug_info; cannot be processed at runtime: relocation ignored
Undefined                        first referenced

 symbol                             in file

__gmpz_limbs_write                  ../libhogweed.so

__gmpz_limbs_finish                 ../libhogweed.so

__gmpz_limbs_modify                 ../libhogweed.so

__gmpn_zero                         ../libhogweed.so

__gmpz_roinit_n                     ../libhogweed.so

__gmpn_cnd_sub_n                    ../libhogweed.so

__gmpn_cnd_add_n                    ../libhogweed.so

__gmpz_limbs_read                   ../libhogweed.so

ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `pkcs1-conv'
Current working directory /root/nettle-3.0/tools
```

I installed `gmp` 6.0.0 to `/usr/local`, then - in the `nettle` directory -, I ran `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`, then `make` and got the error above.

Comment: for me this meant "-lgmp needs to come after -lhogweed" but you already have that so... (gmp 6.1 etc.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks nettle is finding an older version first. Have you tried?

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-include-path=/usr/local/include --with-lib-path=/usr/local/lib
```

I found the options by using `./configure --help`.

Comment: From deleted answer: Thanks. This works for me ./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/gmp"